# If else statement vimrc for custom key mapping

Tags: vimrc

So, I can create custom key mapping for specific directories like this:

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead <name of directory>*  map <key> :! <command here>`

This only executes the command in that specific directory.  Say I have F5 as key, then outside of that directory, F5 does not do anything special.  To add F5 to another directory, I simply repeat the above code and change name of directory and commands.  This would get make my vimrc to be very messy if I have many directories that I need F5 to do stuff (just for example).

Is it possible to do something like this? 
`

```
if (directory = <dirA>) then 
   execute this command 
else if (directory = <dirB>) then 
   execute this command instead
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure we already have a duplicate of this question on the site.

Comment: @statox i think i found it... should have searched prior to answering i suppose.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you for finding it! It's not that bad that you wrote an answer as long as we are able to link the duplicates :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure: use an `<expr>` mapping.

```
nnoremap <expr> <F5> My_mapping()

function! My_mapping
  if getcwd() ==# 'special'
    return 'special mapping'
  else
    return ''
  endif
endfunction
```

This differs slightly from the example given, in that it is re-evaluated each time the key is hit. I do this so that changes to the pwd during editing are propagated to the mapping. If you *only* care about directory at startup, you can use

```
if getcwd() ==# 'special'
  nnoremap <F5> <blah>
endif
```